# OpenLayers - feature.getId is not a function

Tags: openlayers, geojson, features

I am getting this error in vector source when features are specified. The features are getting successfully and the array contains the features

```
var features = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'geoJSON-url',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(json1) {
        $.each(json1, function (key, data) {
            if (key == 'features') {
                $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                    if (v.type=='Feature') {
                            features[k] = v;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
    var source = new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSON(),
      features: features
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your AJAX success function is creating an array of GeoJSON features.  OpenLayers expects OpenLayers features.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'geoJSON-url',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(json1) {
        features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json1);
    }
});
```

It would be simpler to let OpenLayers asychronously load and parse the URL

```
var source = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: 'geoJSON-url'
});
```

Comment: Actually, I tried to create cluster , the features is displayed on the map, but if I use this source to create a cluster source, I get an error - cannot read getType property with null.
Looking for a solution found a solution using ajax so i tried with it.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Comment: This is my geoJSON file is bad for a cluster. Thanks for answer